# WooCommerce digital downloads throw 403 forbidden error

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am implementing force woocommerce download, but after checkout I was not able to download the file. It gives me 403 forbidden error. I went through all the possible solution found on google but I didn't find any luck: 
- I had tried checking file permission and all permission modes are ok.

- Moreover I had tried disabling all the plugin except woocommerce and activating 2017 theme
- There is htaccess file on woocommerce_uploads folder and I guess it is necessary to prevent direct download
- Tried clearing up cache
- request server if any setting from their end

Please share me any idead regarding to this issue, I am really having hard time to fixed this error.

Screenshot: product setting: https://prnt.sc/jevaeu
error: https://prnt.sc/jevasb

Thanks

Comment: What's the full path that you're looking at when you get the 403? Not the domain, but everything after it.

Comment: Thank you Cameron for your response. As mentioned I am using woocommerce force download feature which let user to download only from checkout , wp-content/uploads/woocommerce-uploads/2018/05/filename

Comment: Is there no query string?

Comment: yes there is ,,,it looks something like this https://staging2.papertanks.com.au/?download_file=2662&amp;order=wc_order_5af1b62282398&amp;email=adhsushil7%40gmail.com&amp;key=61528a67-f270-4538-bf6b-c6f4e9d9b008

Comment: @foamymedia Could you please help me on this...Thanks